# Resolve a subdomain of a CNAME

Tags: dns, domain, subdomain, cname

At ***provider 1*** I have an account with the DNS record:

```
domain.provider1.org    IN    NS    1.2.3.4
```

The resolution of `foobar.domain.provider1.org` is handled by my own DNS server.

Now, ***provider 2*** has an great offer for a top-level domain where I would set just a CNAME:

```
domain.org    IN    CNAME    domain.provider1.org
```

How are subdomains of provider 2 handled? For instance, is the delegation of `foobar.domain.org` to `foobar.domain.provider1.org` working?

**EDIT:** My intention is to mirror all subdomains from `domain.provider1.org` to `domain.org` without maintaining a separate name server for each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How are subdomains of provider 2 handled?

Since you didn't specify `NS` record for `domain.org`, the authoritative DNS server for `domain.org` and all the subdomains is still provider2. Thus subdomains have to be added at provider2 interface or they won't exist.

> For instance, is the delegation of foobar.domain.org to foobar.domain.provider1.org working?

No, it won't work because there is no record for `foobar.domain.org`. With the current settings `domain.org` will be resolved as alias for `domain.provider1.org`. However, since you don't have any A or AAAA record for `domain.provider1.org`, the resolution will stop there.

What you probably wanted was this at provider2:

```
domain.org    IN    NS    1.2.3.4
```

And this at your own DNS server at 1.2.3.4:

```
foobar.domain.org    IN    CNAME    foobar.domain.provider1.org
```

Comment: Even for the main domain `domain.provider1.org` the specified nameserver is contacted which yields the A/AAAA record. This works. Unluckily, subdomains of CNAMEs doesn't work. I just want to mirror **all** subdomains from one domain to another domain.

Comment: Sorry i don't think that is possible. At best you can implement wildcard CNAME: https://serverfault.com/a/44635 and direct all the subdomains to a single domain. If this is web related, you could have the web server at target location read the current subdomain and redirect to different domain with regexp ...

Comment: For non-http traffic you can use TCP and UDP proxy too, so if you don't mind the extra work and connections being done, that would be the way for you to achieve desired behavior.

Comment: In general, it is not web related. Most of the servers have non-HTTP traffic. An entire proxy is not an option. If it is not possible, as you pointed out, the easiest way is probably to set both domains to `IN NS 1.2.3.4` and duplicate all subdomains just on my nameserver. Thank you, anyway!